# Setting up DNS server with bind9 issue: creating TCP socket: address not available

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind

I am trying to setup a dns server on ubuntu. With

> sudo systemctl status bind9

I get

```
Apr 17 10:14:21 dns named[1002]: no longer listening on fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:14:21 dns named[1002]: listening on IPv6 interface eno2, fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:14:21 dns named[1002]: creating TCP socket: address not available
Apr 17 10:15:06 dns named[1002]: no longer listening on fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:15:06 dns named[1002]: listening on IPv6 interface eno2, fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:15:06 dns named[1002]: creating TCP socket: address not available
Apr 17 10:15:51 dns named[1002]: no longer listening on fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:15:51 dns named[1002]: listening on IPv6 interface eno2, fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
Apr 17 10:15:51 dns named[1002]: creating TCP socket: address not available
Apr 17 10:16:36 dns named[1002]: no longer listening on fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53
```

I don`t understand from where

> fe80::9903:2b67:b230:aaaa%3#53

is coming from, it is not in my configuration or ansible playbook.

dig and nslookup work, but not ping:

$ dig gitlab.bobby

dig gitlab.bobby

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> gitlab.bobby
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 151
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gitlab.bobby.      IN  A

;; Query time: 439 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Du apr 17 13:43:40 EEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44




ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:41:a9:a0:e4:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.138/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 71048sec preferred_lft 71048sec
    inet6 fe80::a7fb:95aa:eceb:644e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.9.100.6/16 brd 10.9.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::801:28e7:2f5b:5191/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The setup is run with an ansible playbook, that I tested in test servers and it worked.
systemd-resolved was using socket 53 as well, killed, restarted etc no change.

Anything I can try?

Comment: When you'll describe what system has an `eno2` interface with index 3 (here there's a `tun0` interface with index 3) maybe things could become more clear. Maybe your automatic configuration settings use the wrong interface from the wrong system?

Comment: Find out which process has port 53 open: `sudo lsof -i:53`. Depending on which Unix/Linux you're using, you may  need to read `man dnsmasq systemd-dnsmasq` in addition to `man lsof`.

Comment: Your `dig gitlab bobby` command failed! That's what the `Status NXDOMAIN` (Non-Existent DOMAIN) means. The DNS server you used (not your Bind9) successfully said "I don't know the IP address of `gitlab`". No IP address was returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the port being blocked, but systemd-resolved.

I solved the issue like it described here:

https://kifarunix.com/configure-openvpn-clients-to-use-specific-dns-server/

```
apt install openresolv
```

Add this to your client ovpn file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Start openvpn on client:

```
openvpn client-1.ovpn
```

Check that it works
cat /etc/resolv.conf